# Splitting an item list using regex

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

To start I have a string that is composed of a list of items the items can be spliced by an ***enumerator*** (comma/'and') or an ***article*** ('a'/'an'/'the'). Note that the article can be omitted if there is an enumerator and vice-versa.

For example let's look at this input:

```
a paper, leaf the clock and an angel
```

This must be divided into:

- `a paper`
- `leaf`
- `the clock`
- `an angel`

The first example has only items with single names, so let's take a look at another example:

```
a paper with some letters, a torn leaf and clock and an angel doll
```

this must be divided into:

- `a paper with some letters`
- `torn leaf`
- `clock`
- `an angel doll`

I already tried some regex for this and the closest I came was using:

```
(?:\b(?P<article>the|an|a)\b)\s(?P<object>\b.+?\b(?=\b(?:the|an|a|$)\b))
```

Of course I'm not taking into account ','/'and' splitting as I couldn't figure it out, sadly.

Lastly as you can see I used groups to identify/separate the ***object*** from the ***article***. And that would be great if it could be that way. What are your suggestions?

Comment: I'd suggest using appropriate tools, like NLTK, to parse a natural language.

Comment: You've kept the article in some cases, and dropped it in others. Is this an error? Or is there some rule that you're leaving out?

Comment: The article can either be there or can be omitted if there is a enumerator (and or comma)! @Mike

Comment: @georg I understand what you said and it would probably be a better idea... but the license on NLTK is for non-commercial only.. and I might need at some time to actually use this for commercial stuff.

Comment: @xDGameStudios: NLTK is licensed under Apache 2.0. (https://github.com/nltk/nltk/wiki/FAQ). If does allow any commercial use and is non-copyleft, that it, you don't have to distribute your software under the same terms.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `re.split()`

```py
import re

a = "a paper with some letters, a torn leaf and clock and an angel doll"

### put every separator you want to remove after a |
re.split(', |and |a ',a)
# result:
['', 'paper with some letters', '', 'torn leaf ', 'clock ', '', 'angel doll']
```

if you need to keep the separator just use brackets:

```py
[i for i in re.split('(, |and |a )',a) if i]
# result:
['a ', 'paper with some letters', ', ', 'a ', 'torn leaf ', 'and ', 'clock ', 'and ', 'an angel doll']
```

Comment: As I said, I need to keep the article there (a/an/the) to do some post processing!

Comment: Okay I get you... but then again... I needed to catch the groups <b>article</b> and <b>object</b>

Answer (score 0):

Enumerate all your cases, which are small, in descending order of what will match in a regex with `re.split()`:

```py
import re

s = "a paper with some letters, a torn leaf and clock and an angel doll"

re.split(r'^an |^a |^the |, and a |, and an |, and the |, and |, and an |, an |, the |, a | and an | and | an | the', s)
# ['', 'paper with some letters', 'torn leaf', 'clock', 'angel doll']
```

The rest is just cleaning up `''`, and so on.

To keep the matched things, wrap the regex in parentheses, as per the docs:

```py
re.split(r'(^an |^a |^the |, and a |, and an |, and the |, and |, and an |, an |, the |, a | and an | and | an | the )', s)

# ['', 'a ', 'paper with some letters', ', a ', 'torn leaf', ' and ', 'clock', ' and an ', 'angel doll']
```

Comment: If there is one, I need to keep the article there though (for post-processing)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the specific task I wanted to solve I came across another idea,
The steps are the following:

- add a default article (the) whenever there is an 'and' or ',' not followed by and article

```py
"( and|,) (?!the|an|a)|^(?!the|an|a)" # replace with " the "
```

- remove every 'and' or ',' from the input text (now every object should be separate by articles)

```py
"( and|,) " # replace with " "
```

- separate the input into article + everything except article

```py
"(?P<article>the|an|a) (?P<object>.+?(?= (?:the|an|a)\b)|[^$]*)"
```

PS: if anyone knows an alternative for this last regex, feel free to post! :)

Answer (score 0):

By using re.sub() we can replace the particular strings with new line.
Here in re.sub(), you can add the articles whatever that need to be replaced with new line.

**Sample code:**

```
s = 'a paper with some letters, a torn leaf and clock and an angel doll'

print(re.sub(r'(and|,)\s', r"\0\n", s))
```

**output:**

```
a paper with some letters
a torn leaf 
clock 
an angel doll
```